# A List of כל אתין and their interpretations

Tags: talmud-gemara, drush

In Pesachim, 22a, the following braita is cited:

> כִּדְתַנְיָא: שִׁמְעוֹן הָעַמְסוֹנִי, וְאָמְרִי לַהּ נְחֶמְיָה הָעַמְסוֹנִי, הָיָה דּוֹרֵשׁ כׇּל ׳אֶתִּים׳ שֶׁבַּתּוֹרָה, כֵּיוָן שֶׁהִגִּיעַ לְ״אֶת ה׳ אֱלֹהֶיךָ תִּירָא״ פֵּירַשׁ. אָמְרוּ לוֹ תַּלְמִידָיו: רַבִּי, כׇּל ׳אֶתִּים׳ שֶׁדָּרַשְׁתָּ מָה תְּהֵא עֲלֵיהֶן? אָמַר לָהֶם: כְּשֵׁם שֶׁקִּבַּלְתִּי שָׂכָר עַל הַדְּרִישָׁה, כָּךְ אֲנִי מְקַבֵּל שָׂכָר עַל הַפְּרִישָׁה. עַד שֶׁבָּא רַבִּי עֲקִיבָא וְדָרַשׁ: ״אֶת ה׳ אֱלֹהֶיךָ תִּירָא״ — לְרַבּוֹת תַּלְמִידֵי חֲכָמִים

In the case of "kabed et avicha v'et imecha" the "et" creates a larger, more inclusive group so that the halacha is applied to more than just father and mother.

This is summed up by Rashi in Ketubot 103a that "כל אתין רבויין"

Is there a master list of all the "et" uses and the drasha (expansive understanding) that is made for each one?

Comment: Someone wrote a sefer on this topic. It had Es in the title.

Comment: @N.T. **את לרבות : דרושים וביאורים על כל תיבת את שבתורה** , ר' יחיאל מיכל יאסילאווסקי, ברוקלין, נוא יארק, תשנ"ז

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**את לרבות : דרושים וביאורים על כל תיבת את שבתורה**

ר' יחיאל מיכל יאסילאווסקי

(ברוקלין, נוא יארק, תשנ"ז)

"Et Lerabot" by Rabbi Jechiel Miche Josilowski

[image]

Comment: Availble here: https://www.ebay.com/itm/373131029781

Answer (score 4):

Although I don't have a master list of all the “et” I think we should make our own :)

Here is a list of everything I found so far (I quoted the relevant parts, but one must look in the context to understand what it's saying. There is also a machloket if we make drashot out of “et” so keep that in mind):

Beresheit Raba 1:14- אֵת הַשָּׁמַיִם, לְרַבּוֹת חַמָּה וּלְבָנָה וּמַזָּלוֹת, וְאֵת הָאָרֶץ, לְרַבּוֹת אִילָנוֹת וּדְשָׁאִין וְגַן עֵדֶן

Brachot 36b- וְרַחֲמָנָא אָמַר: ״וַעֲרַלְתֶּם עׇרְלָתוֹ אֶת פִּרְיוֹ״, אֶת הַטָּפֵל לְפִרְיוֹ, וּמַאי נִיהוּ — שׁוֹמֵר לַפְּרִי

Eruvin 4b- שְׂעָרוֹ נָמֵי דְּאוֹרָיְיתָא הוּא, דְּתַנְיָא: ״וְרָחַץ אֶת כָּל בְּשָׂרוֹ״ — אֶת הַטָּפֵל לִבְשָׂרוֹ, וְזֶהוּ שֵׂעָר!

Pesachim 22b- אֶת ה׳ אֱלֹהֶיךָ תִּירָא״ — לְרַבּוֹת תַּלְמִידֵי חֲכָמִי

Ketuvot 103a- דְּתַנְיָא: ״כַּבֵּד אֶת אָבִיךָ וְאֶת אִמֶּךָ״, ״אֶת אָבִיךָ״ — זוֹ אֵשֶׁת אָבִיךָ, ״וְאֶת אִמֶּךָ״ — זוֹ בַּעַל אִמֶּךָ

Bava Kama 41b- נפקא להו מאת בשרו את הטפל לבשרו מאי ניהו עורו

Menachot 11b- את לרבות קורט אחר ור"ש את לא דריש

Menachot 60b- את המנחה לרבות שאר מנחות כגון מנחת נכרים מנחת נשים להגשה

Bechorot 6b- ור' שמעון לאסור חלבו מנא ליה נפקא ליה מאת הגמל ורבנן אתים לא דרשי

Braita of Rebbi Eliezer of 32 rules: Example of Rule 1 (which is inclusion): שנ' ו פקד את שרה. אלו נא' וייי פקד שרה, הייתי אומ' שרה לבדה נפקדה, ת"ל את, רבה את הכל, מלמד שכל העקרות נפקדו עמה.

Braita of Rebbi Eliezer of 32 rules: Example of Rule 1 (which is inclusion): וכן הוא אומ' צחק עשה לי אלהים. כיוצא בדבר, את פני מבין חכמה. אלו נא' פני מבין חכמה, הייתי אומ' לשעתו בלבד, וכשהוא אומר את, רבה את הכל לדורות ולדורי דורות

Zohar Yitro 289- את הקולות, הוא כמו שאמר וארא את ה', וארא ה' לא כתוב, אלא את ה', שפירושו, שראה השכינה שנקראת את, אף כאן וכל העם רואים הקולות לא נאמר, אלא את הקולות, (שסובב גם כן על ראיית השכינה).

Zohar Yitro 347- וידבר אלקים, השם אלקים הוא גבורה, את (יורה) שנכלל בימין, כמו שלמדנו, את השמים הוא ימין, ואת הארץ הוא שמאל

It would be better if instead of everyone adding separate answers everyone should participate and edit or comment on any sources I missed. This is just the beginning of the master list!

את קין את אחיו את הבל. ג' אֶתִים רִבּוּיִים הֵם, מְלַמֵּד, שֶׁתְּאוֹמָה נוֹלְדָה עִם קַיִן, וְעִם הֶבֶל נוֹלְדוּ שְׁתַּיִם, לְכָךְ נֶאֱמַר וַתֹּסֶף - רש״י על בראשית ד:א

וְרַבִּי יוֹסֵי כּוּלְּהוּ כִּדְקָאָמְרַתְּ אֶת לְרַבּוֹת צַוּוֹאוֹת וְקַבָּלוֹת (סוטה י״ז,א

אלא לקמן דרש רש"י מן יתור לשון של את כי כל את לרבות בא ומרבה שאפילו מה שאתה מוביל לה לא תתן (כלי יקר ויקרא כ׳״ו:ג

אבל אם אתה דורש תיבת את משמע שהלכו לרעות את הצאן במקום מרעה (חזקוני בראשית ל״ז:י״ב

הסכין.  מדכתיב והכינו את אשר יביאו הך את נרמז בו סכין מלשון לאתים ולמזמרות: (באר היטב, אורח חיים ר״ן:ג

את והב בסופה״ - שני מצורעים היו - ברכות נ״ד ב

פָּתַח וְאָמַר, (ויקרא יט) אֶת שַׁבְּתוֹתַי. אֶת לְאַסְגָּאָה תְּחוּם שַׁבָּת דְּאִיהוּ תְּרֵין אַלְפִין אַמִּין לְכָל סִטְרָא (ויקהל ר"ז א). וּבְגִין
כָּךְ אַסְגֵי אֶת. (הקדמה י״ב לספר הזהר

וְאַחֲרֵי כֵן קָבַר אַבְרָהָם אֶת שָׂרָה אִשְׁתּוֹ,
לְשָׂרָה לָא כְּתִיב אֶלָּא אֶת שָׂרָה לְאַסְגָּאָה
חַוָּה - זוהר חיי שרה ט״ו

בהמולו את בשר ערלתו. בְּאַבְרָהָם לֹא נֶאֱמַר "אֵת", לְפִי שֶׁלֹּא הָיָה חָסֵר אֶלָּא חִתּוּךְ בָּשָׂר, שֶׁכְּבָר נִתְמָעֵךְ עַל יְדֵי תַשְׁמִישׁ; אֲבָל יִשְׁמָעֵאל שֶׁהָיָה יֶלֶד, הֻזְקַק לַחְתֹּךְ עָרְלָה וְלִפְרֹעַ הַמִּילָה, לְכָךְ נֶאֱמַר בּוֹ "אֵת"
רש״י על בראשית י״ז:כ״ה

וברכת
את ה' אלקיך. את – לרבות ברכה לבעל הבית - אבודרהם

כה תברכו את בני ישראל - את לרבות מלאכי השרת - רבינו בחיי